# MongoDB: do query for search to all fields in array objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I've this document in `users` collection:

```
 {
    "email": "user@email.net",
    "password": "123123",
    "userFriends": [{
            friendName: "Boomer",
            friendDescription: "Hello i am Boomer, how are you ?",
            timeStamp: "000000000"
        },
        {
            friendName: "Fizx",
            friendDescription: "Hello i am Fizx, how are you ?",
            timeStamp: "000000000"
        },
        {
            friendName: "Osta",
            friendDescription: "Hello i am Osta, how are you ?",
            timeStamp: "000000000"
        },
        {
            friendName: "Ftak",
            friendDescription: "Hello i am Ftak, how are you ?",
            timeStamp: "000000000"
        },

    ]
}
```

`userFriends` sub-document has three fields

Suppose that you're in a website and there is Search Input
The user can type anything in Search Input

If the user typed the Friend Name or Friend description, I want to execute query to fetch/find the friend data,
But i don't want to use `find({friendName: 'Osta'})` or whatever query that let you get the data by specifying the field name

I tried `$elemMatch` but it gives me one result
And `$text, $search` but it gives me the whole document, not the specific item in the sub-document.

Anyway, I want to search for all the sub-document fields in just One parameter without specifying the friendName or friendDescription

So the searching would be like twitter search, if you just type user name you'll get the user Account, if you just type description you'll get the user account, etc.

Anyone have any ideas or can help? I am newbie in mongoDB!

Comment: You can use `$or`. So the value typed by the user will be match to fieldA or fieldB...Something like this: `find({$or:[{"arrayField.fieldA":userInput}, {"arrayField.fieldB":userInput}...]})`

Comment: @Minsky Yes, It's a good approach, but if i had too many fields in the document it would be messy

Comment: so... you want the user to type in the search bar Osta or Osta description and get just the profile of the user that matches that strings? But you want to make it like twitter in order for just tapping "Os...", you get Osta or some similar name?

Comment: @KevinBuguecio doesn't matter if it's a complete word or not, i think if i want to make it like twitter (" Os... ") i'll use Regex

Comment: @KevinBuguecio but the real question, how to do query that searches for field by the value and this query applied to all the fields